# Is it possible to build a statically linked version of Qt 5.3 for windows on Linux?

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, cross-platform, wine

Is it possible to build a statically linked windows executable for Qt 5.3 from a Linux OS like Ubuntu using wine?

I tried searching the web but could not find anything up to date.

Comment: Using wine it will work exactly as if you did it on Windows, as long as you install the compiler under wine. You can also cross-compile without using wine.

Comment: @KubaOber Thanks, have you perhaps got any links or info on how to cross compile for Qt 5.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 please?

Comment: Using wine or using a cross-compiler?

Comment: @KubaOber Preferably a cross-compiler please Kuba.